# Copy the newest two files and append the date

Tags: linux, bash

I'm looking for a way to copy the newest `.gz` files I have in `Dir A` to `Dir B`, and append the date to that files.

Example:

**Dir A**

- cinema.gz
- radio.gz
- cars.txt
- camera.gz

**Dir B**

- cinema.gz.20200310
- radio.gz.20200310

Using following command I can copy the newest `.gz` files to `dirb`

`cp $(ls -1t /dira *gz | head -2) "dirb"`

However I don't find a way to change append the date to the filename.

I was trying something like this:

`cp $(ls -1t /dira *gz | head -2) "dirb/*.$(date +%F_%R)"`

But don't works at all.

Your help please :)

Comment: My idea would be to grab the names one at a time, storing it in a variable, appending the date to the variable, and then use the variable to copy. I'm not sure how to implement it but seems like it may be easier than doing both at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for TO_MOVE in `ls -t *.gz | head -n2`; do 
    cp $TO_MOVE dirb/;
    mv dirb/$TO_MOVE dirb/$TO_MOVE.`date +%Y%m%d`;
done
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: I think your totally wrong @Igor F. . The question is about a specific task and not about a particular functioning of a command or so. It follows there's no, as you says, "long -term value". Moreover the chunk of code are really simple and trivial (The basic usage of cp and mv). I think that on this kind of question ther's nothing ton say and nothing to explain aside to show code.

Comment: If it is so, then the question (and the answers to it) should not be on Stack Overflow. What purpose do they serve now, that the OP has gotten its answer? If, however, other users in the future are also to benefit from the answer, then an explanation would certainly be helpful.

Comment: The question is too specific to be useful to others in the future, since it concerns a practical need of an individual in a specific task and not the functioning of a command or other. Then, sorry, look at the other answers, do you find that the comments add something useful to the code?

Answer (score 0):

You can't compact this into one cp command sadly. However you can do this.

```
for f in $(ls -1t/dira gz | head -2); do
    cp "$f" "dirb/$f.$(date +%F_%R | sed 's;/;\\/;g')"
done
```

Edit: I pipe the date through sed to escape the '/' characters in the date string (Otherwise cp will interpret them as directory names).

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code from parent directory of dira and dirb;

```
ls -1t dira/*.gz | head -2 | while read -r line; do cp $line dirb/${line#*/}.$(date +%F_%R); done
```

I'm using while to loop over the files and `${line#*/}` trims the directory name. Let me know if you have any query.